# How do you interrupt a process after starting it with exec()?

Tags: php, exec

If I start a process with exec(), how can I later terminate that process, with say pressing/sending the "q" key.  Right now, when I execute the process, PHP will hang until it finishes and returns.

Answer (score 1):

```
function PsExec($commandJob) { 

    $command = $commandJob.' > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!'; 
    exec($command ,$op); 
    $pid = (int)$op[0]; 

    if($pid!="") return $pid; 

    return false; 
}
```

later on...
        exec("kill -9 $pid", $output);

Comment: Hi Christo, 

I was wondering if you could elaborate on your suggestion and help me customize it for my needs. 

1.  Could you explain what is going on with the  "& echo $!" part of the "> /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $! "   
  Maybe if you could explain the whole thing, that may be helpful, so I can make sure I am on the same page. 

2.  I need to send the error output to a particular file.  I'm not sure how to make the above line of code do that and have it still work. 


Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hehe, Jason, if you want to redirect to a file, you certainly aren't going to want that syntax! I think all you want is:

Comment: Whoops, sorry, entry issue above... If you want to redirect to a file, you certainly aren't going to want that syntax! I think all you want is: $command = $commandJob.' >> myParticularLogFile.txt 2>myParticularErrLogFile.txt & echo$!';

2>&1 is just redirecting stderr to &1, which in turn is shorthand for /dev/null in my post.

The & echo $! forks (&) echo $! to output the pid so you can keep it. You need the pid to be able to kill later.

Comment: why not just update your answer instead of adding to comments?

Answer (score 0):

if you want your script to exit regardless of wheter the exec is done, you can redirect the out put to another file,

```
exec("php dothis.php >> file.log");
```

i hope that helps you

Comment: Ibrahim,  Thank you for this suggestion. I, however, need a way to terminate the process started with exec and I do not think this would solve that.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `pcntl_fork` and `pcntl_exec` to launch your program and `posix_kill` to terminate it.

Answer (score 0):

> If I start a process with exec(), how can I later terminate that process, with say pressing/sending the "q" key.

Instead of using `exec`, you could look at using [`proc_open`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-open.php), which requires that you pass in an array specifying three [streams](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.stream.php) -- one for `stdin`, one for `stdout` and one for `stderr`.

This will let you easily feed input into the program while processing output, without blocking *just* waiting for it to execute.  You can later use [`proc_terminate`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.proc-terminate.php) to viciously murder it, if needed.

Comment: Hi Charles,  thank you for your suggestion.  I never used proc_open before and had a question that I hope you can answer for me.  Would it be right to say that the "array descriptor" is for the process executed by the command.  and the pipes array is how the php script will communicate with the new process?   Also does the resource handle automatically close at the end of the script, or do you need to manually close it?